# Zizaco entrust does not create the entrust.php

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, entrust

Why the file entrust.php is not created when I run this:

```
php artisan vendor:publish
```

I'm following [this](https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust) config and this is my **composer.json**

```
"zizaco/entrust": "5.2.x-dev"
```

"You can also publish the configuration for this package to further customize table names and model namespaces.
Just use php artisan vendor:publish and a entrust.php file will be created in your app/config directory."
But the file entrust.php is not created. 
What can I do? This is odd.

Comment: Maybe you are missing permissions, Try sudo if you are in linux? or open cmd as administrator in windows?

Comment: I'm using linux and I have permissions.

Comment: yeap...now I read it too..you are awesome to respond so quickly! thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the link you provided they say `and, if it does not appear, manually copy the /vendor/zizaco/entrust/src/config/config.php file in your config directory and rename it entrust.php.`

Answer (score 1):

just try this
add

> "zizaco/entrust": "5.2.x-dev" in composer.json

then composer update.
Then in your config/app.php add

```
Zizaco\Entrust\EntrustServiceProvider::class,
```

in the providers array and

```
'Entrust'   => Zizaco\Entrust\EntrustFacade::class,
```

Next try in your terminal to publish and see in your config

> php artisan vendor:publish
>   --provider="Zizaco\Entrust\EntrustServiceProvider"

[check link for how to use zizaco](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36152456/laravel-5-2-integrate-entrust-package-create-role-and-permissions-and-access-i)

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by running

```
php artisan config:cache
```

Before running

```
php artisan vendor:publish
```

Answer (score 0):

run this command

```
php artisan config:cache
```

then run

```
php artisan vendor:publish
```